# Angular/NGRX breaks the output

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have this simple code where I am trying just add a reducer to the module.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import {Action} from '@ngrx/store';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

class Book {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

class BookStore {
  books: Book[];
}


const ADD_BOOK = '[Book] Add book'; 


export function addReducer(state = BookStore, action: Action) {
  console.log(state, action);

  switch (action.type) {

  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>Hello!</h1>',

})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ count: addReducer })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And as soon as I add this line of code

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ count: addReducer })
```

my page becomes empty and without 'Hello!' word and I see no errors in the console.

My versions of libraries:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

How can I figure out what is happening?
Probably I need to add some additional features into my reducer?

Comment: Seems like sort of leak of memory or infinite recursion.

Comment: Try upgrading angular to v6, or downgrading ngrx to v4.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
After updating angular to the newest version it works fine.